# turn off off fliers in sns.boxplot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I'd like to hide the fliers in `sns.boxplot()`, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've looked on here and there is not a solution that I can get working.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to display them, you could do:

```py
seaborn.boxplot(showfliers=False)
```

I hope it helps.